# Autohotkey running application minimized not working

Tags: autohotkey

New to AHK. Trying to start a notepad minimized (or maximized) but it's starting always in a normal size. I use Windows 10. Any ideas? My code below:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

^j::
   Run, Notepad.exe, min
Return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^j::
    Run, Notepad.exe, , Min
Return
```

This is the default syntax for "Run" in AHK:

```
Run, Target [, WorkingDir, Max|Min|Hide|UseErrorLevel, OutputVarPID]
```